# WPF: creating an icon with overlay label

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to create a custom control which is an icon and a label overlaid on it,

so I have an icon and on top of it(top/topright/topleft etc)I want to put my label.

I tried using 3x3 grid, so the icon is in the center and according to the value of the anchor(top, topright, topleft) the label should be overlaid on the icon

so in code I am using Grid.SetRow & Set Column according to the value that was set(top right is row=0, column =2 etc)

```
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <usercontrols:ImageMakerControl x:Name="xIcon" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SetAsFontImageWithSize="20" ImageType="Save" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <Label x:Name="xCounterLbl" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource $LabelStyle}">
            <Grid>
                <Ellipse Fill="Red" Height="{Binding ElementName=xLabelTB,Path=ActualHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=xLabelTB,Path=ActualWidth}" />
                <TextBox x:Name="xLabelTB" FontFamily="Open Sans" Text="99+" FontSize="6.5" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Label>
    </Grid>
```

this is how it looks like:

[image]

and I am only able to achieve my goal using Margin

what should be the right way to do it or what container should I use?

Comment: Do you know of the Grid.ColumnSpan and Grid.RowSpan properties?

Comment: Yes I have previously tried setting them with different values, but the results was not what I was looking for

Comment: You don't need to use Grid.Row and Grid.Column. Just place them in a Grid and adjust their positions by margin.